# separate limiter values with a pipe (|)

Tags: magento2, categories

I am trying to work out how I can separate my limiter values with a **pipe (|)**

Ideally, the end result will be **View: 48 | 120 | ALL,** at present I have been able to get **View: 48 120 ALL**

This is what I have used so far:

```
<div class="field limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View:') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
            <a data-role="limiter" href="#" data-value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                class="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_limit ?>
            </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily done by CSS.

I always prefer CSS for this kind of tweaks.

```
.limiter .control a + a::before {
   content: " | ";
}
```

It will Add a Pipe separator between a tag

Demo can be found at [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pawankparmar/nkLtvrde/)

Hope above will help!

Comment: didn't even come to my mind to use less, ive made a slight change on the above but have achieved the desired result

Comment: @Paul'Whippet'McGuane, Glad to know :)

Comment: causes a slight styling issue but I am hopefully I can fix that

Comment: Yes, you can add more class in hierarchy to avoid issue.

Comment: already solved with some additional attributes added. perfect solution

Comment: Great @ Thank you @Paul'Whippet'McGuane :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using **PHP implode(),** check below modified code:

```
<div class="field limiter">
    <label class="label" for="limiter">
        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View:') ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
            <a data-role="limiter" href="#" data-value="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_key ?>"<?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                class="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo implode("|",$_limit) ?>
            </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it does not like, gave me a screen full of errors :(

Comment: how about removing implode `echo "|",$_limit` ? have you tried